# Embedding scalable images in R Markdown HTML output file

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I'm currently trying to find a way to embed external images (PNG) in my R markdown HTML output file in a **scalable way**.

What I have tried so far only sets them to a width equal to the space available in HTML file (don't know how much that is in pixels, maybe around 800px) even though the original image size is ~1500x700.

What I would like is that when I increase the window size of the HTML viewer that also the images increase, at least up to their original resolution. Down-scaling works without problems.

My attempts:

````
```{r fig.width=100, fig.height=55, echo=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("images/image.png")
grid.raster(img)
```
````

and

```
<img src="images/image.png">
```

...without success.

Anybody got an idea how to do that? I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `out.width` instead of `fig.width` and `fig.height`, with percentage, which will be percentage of the text area. You can use it with `include_graphics()`. If you do not set `out.height`, the ratio will stay ok.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width='80%'}
knitr::include_graphics("images/image.png")
```
````